# Within headers, images with alt text vs. text

Tags: html, seo, alt-attribute

Do search engines treat the alt text of an image placed within an h1 tag the same way they would treat regular text placed in an h1 tag?

I gave a search through here looking for an answer to this question, but was only able to find information on image replacement and the infamous h1 debate.

For example would:

```
<h1><img src="#" alt="Contact Us" /></h1>
```

Act the same as:

```
<h1>Contact Us</h1>
```

In the electronic eye of a search engine?

This seems considerably less "CSS Hacky" than other image replacement techniques like negative text indents, display:none, height:0, or ridiculous z-index integers.

Comment: SEO is off-topic, sorry.

Comment: Where would you suggest posting it?  Webmaster doesn't seem appropriate either -- has nothing to do with managing servers or sites.

I've been having this dilemma myself.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, in an ideal world, we could use image alt within a h1 and be confident about our searchability.
As far as I know (and according to [this blog](http://robbiehammond.com/how-google-handles-alt-text-in-h1-tags)) Google ranks this:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
```

Higher than this:

```
<h1><img alt="Title" src="image.jpg"/></h1>
```

While Yahoo and Bing will not index the image Alt as a page title.

I use a negative text indent personally.

Answer (score 0):

As long as **direct text** in h1 tag ranks better (has stronger influence on page) than alt in image you could consider image replacing techniques like Rowan suggested

Treat your html document like a book with chapters... What would be more readable for you ? a page chapter, that is titled with text or an image?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the object tag for the image, and provide alternative content within the object tag.

```
<h1><object data="contact-us.jpg" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</object></h1>
```

This way the robot sees the text and users see the image.